# Can't give python inputs to Python Interactive Window in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a script that contains python user inputs before executing the rest of the code, but I get stuck when attempting to give any value in VSCode Python Interactive Window.

I've been searching for information about how to give these user inputs to a running instance of an interactive window. I tried following up some issues that I found, but most of them were related to inputs to the jupyter instance, but not for a user prompt, such as [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/446). This is what I get when I start running the script:

[Pop-up window when requesting input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JXlI.png)

But after giving a user input, it does nothing. Even if it's empty.

Does anyone know if this is even possible with the current capabilities? I'm wondering if this issue is just happening to me.